# How to turn off radio button functionality?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I want to use radio buttons just as design element, without any functionality. User should not be able to check or uncheck them.

```
<div id="divRadios">
<input type="radio">
<input type="radio">  
...
</div>
```

I suppose the solution could be to place a separate, empty div over `#divRadios` and give it the higher z-index, but maybe there is a more native way ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You'll only cause confusion and frustration for your users.

Comment: Just use images if you can. Radio buttons will look different on every platform, and will even have different sizes.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens, there will not be any confusion. The buttons are at the bottom of page, as a border, instead of a line.

Comment: @SunSky There's a better solution for that: `border-bottom: 10px dotted red` That'll give you a nice line of circles as a border which *does not* look like radio buttons (and thus doesn't confuse your users).

Comment: @MattiasBuelens, hmm, there is no 3D effect as with radios. But... I will see. Thanks.

Comment: @SunSky If you want 3D effects, make an image and put it as a horizontally repeating background. Alternatively, make it a `border-image` on one border side. Heck, you could even go crazy with CSS3 `border-radius`, `transform` and pseudo-elements to design the slickest border ever in pure CSS (with no images). Just don't abuse radio buttons for that *only* because "they look cool".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the 'disabled' attribute on the radio input element:

```
<div id="divRadios">
<input type="radio" disabled>
<input type="radio" disabled>  
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Don't** use `<input type = 'radio' />` if you don't want user to check

create a `span` or `div` and add `radio` class to it:

```
 .radio{
     -moz-appearance:radio;
     -webkit-appearance:radio; 
    }
```

Comment: You can have a checkbox or radio. The radio appearnace wont be checked..According to the question, the radio is only for show purposes, not for checking. SOS why use a radio button????

Answer (score 2):

Just disable them:

```
<input type="radio" disabled>
```

Comment: but `disabled` changes the appearance (opacity) of the buttons.

Comment: Every browser will style buttons differently. The comments above are correct: If what you want is a border, then use a border. The html @heartcode and I have shown you is the correct way to disable an input.

Answer (score 2):

another way to disable a radio without loosing it's actual style(without 'disabled' tag)

```
    <input type="radio" id="rd1" name="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="rd2" name="radio" style="display: none;">

    <script>
    $( '#rd1' ).click( function(e) { 
        $('#rd2').click();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Prakash, thanks. Finally, the answer on the question, without lessons about tastes.

Comment: @SunSky, has nothing to do with tastes. It has to do with semantics, which is one of the most important things on the web. Don't only cater to people with fully functioning eyes.  Anyway, the piece of code in this answer is ridiculous. What's the point of having a click fire a click on a hidden input???  If you don't want the click firing, just use `e.preventDefault();`. But this question wasn't tagged as a JavaScript question.

Comment: e.preventDefault() doesn't work. did you tried out that code? did you think you know everything?? if so you are the foool. first have your code correct. then look at others'. if you understand the question correctly, then you come to know whose answer is correct. the author want the radio button for design purpose. so it shouldn't be disabled, if so it looses it's actual style. also, if we use css styles to change the appearance of an element to look like radio, then it is not possible to get a look of checked radio ( author asked for both checked and unchecked modes ).

Comment: @Jeffrey and Prakash, you're both missing the point. There's a right way and a wrong way! Don't use semantically-incorrect code just for design. Such code degrades user experience for sight-impaired users and other. If you want a checkbox that is always checked, don't create a click event to click a hidden input. That's ridiculous! Give the input an attribute `checked` and remove any name attribute so that it can't be unclicked. If you don't want it clickable, disable it with the `disabled` attribute and style it with the appropriate CSS. It's not rocket science, if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to the answer by @user2404546, the best solution seems to be just use a regular checkbox but change its appearance:

```
.radio{
     -moz-appearance:radio;
     -webkit-appearance:radio; 
}

<input class="radio" type="checkbox">
```